# FWLSE0227E: Failed to send notification. Reason: FPWSE0009E: Internal server error. No devices found

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I received a success message in my browser after passing the sample message and tag to the adapter.

```
{
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "result": "Notification sent to users subscribed to the tag(s): 'sample'."
}
```

But a notification to the android application was not received.
I am getting the following error message in my console:

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0227E: Failed to send notification. Reason: FPWSE0009E: Internal server error. No devices found.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting "no device found" that it could be one of two:

1. No device successfully registered to push notifications. Can you confirm that your device was registered for push notifications?
2. No device was registered to the specific "sample" tag.

I suggest that you will base your implementation on the Tag notification sample, provided in the following tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/tag-based-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

Comment: 1. Can you pls let me know how to check whether our device is registered to push notifications ? I checked in Mobilefirst Operations console and the Devices tab shows 0 active devices.

Comment: As I wrote. Look at the tutorial and sample, that do that.

Comment: As you mentioned, I am able to receive push notification from the sample app given in the link provided. But when i try the same Pushadapter in my project I receive the  above mentioned error

Comment: Then I suggest that you will compare your implementation. You are missing something.

Comment: I double checked the GCM sender key and id... Its correct. Can you suggest which part of the mobilefirst to look into for the Device registration process ?

Comment: I found now in logcat the following message : GCMHelperClient.unregisterReceivers in GCMHelperClient.java :: unregister:Receiver not registered:null.

Comment: @IdanAdar, link was broken, may I know do u have the latest link?